# delayed job for Rails on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, delayed-job

I start developing a site using Rails 3.x and I need to run multiple jobs parallel. I am locked in Windows for now.

I was able to make delayed job (collectiveidea) work using "rake jobs:work" but it seems like it runs jobs 1 at a time. I tried to run "ruby script\delayed_job" but there is no "fork" under Windows.

Does delayed_job can run parallel under Win? Do I have any other options besides delayed_job?

Thanks.

Comment: A worker does do 1 job at a time.  If you want more workers you can start them in other terminals.

Comment: How can I start multiple workers using "rake jobs:work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start multiple workers, I recommend starting multiple command prompts (or similar) and spawning a worker in each window.  Additionally you can spawn it as a process in the same cmd shell and just spawn several of the processes.

Installing as a process isn't that hard, but I don't have a windows box to validate how to do this.